# When to wrap the InputStream in Java rather than directly using the Reader in case of characters?

Tags: java, serialization, file-io

We can wrap an InputStream and turn it into a Reader by using the InputStreamReader class in java:-

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Is there any benefit of doing this when I already have the Reader available?

Comment: There is no benefit. In fact, it would be broken because you'd wrap an input stream that's already wrapped in another reader.

Comment: "An InputStreamReader is a bridge from byte streams to character streams". That's the only reason you would use it.

Comment: Though the Reader here is well specified, indicating the encoding of the InputStream's bytes. Maybe that other Reader had some problem, like using the default platform encoding. Or and XML text was first read in ISO-8859-1 to pick up the encoding, and then reread with the right encoding.